# Two code snippets involving time-change

Tags: beginner, datetime, comparative-review, qml

I have two snippets that are going to be used in a walkthrough and I'd like some feedback on which one is more easily understandable

## 1

```
    property int hours, minutes, seconds
    property real shift: 0.0
    property bool night

    function timeChanged() {
        var date = new Date();
        hours = date.getUTCHours() + Math.floor(clock.shift);
        minutes = date.getUTCMinutes() + (clock.shift % 1) * 60;
        seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();
        night = (hours < 7 || hours > 19);
    }
```

## 2

```
    property int hours, minutes, seconds
    property real shift
    property bool night

    function timeChanged() {
        var date = new Date;
        hours = shift ? date.getUTCHours() + Math.floor(clock.shift) : date.getHours()
        night = ( hours < 7 || hours > 19 );
        minutes = shift ? date.getUTCMinutes() + ((clock.shift % 1) * 60) : date.getMinutes()
        seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();
    }
```

I personally feel that instantiating the shift variable and skipping the `?:` operator altogether is a better approach.

Note that both these snippets are aimed at a tutorial for people who are new to QML, and therefore I am charged with picking the one that seems simplest and clearest to people who don't know a lot about QML.

Comment: What's the difference between `shift` and `clock.shift`? Where is `clock` defined? Finally, why can one version work without using the non-UTC versions. In short, I see far more differences than the ternary operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I definitely think sample #1 is more readable. The main reason is the (lack of) ternary operator. Although any programmer should understand it, it increases the amount of code you have to read. With sample #1 you can quickly skip the parts after `+` in the `hours` and `minutes` assignments, whereas with `? :` you have to read more carefully.

Also, in sample #2 you basically add handling of a special case without needing it, adding unneeded complexity.

Another bonus in sample #1 is that `night` is not defined in the middle of the hours/minutes/seconds block, so the code is more logically grouped.

By the way, I think the use of `shift` should be documented with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know QML and I can pretty well understand what is going on in sample #1. The use of the `? :` syntax could be confusing to someone new to the language.

Also, the example to define `shift` is a good one and is very readable.

Comment: Looks to me like a ternary operator, which any programmer should be able to understand.

Comment: I disagree, the ternary operator is quite common for people who have a FP background / are in the habit of shortening their code in C-like languages.

Comment: @Ed: Arnab is right. That is my concern with the ternary operator, the OP alluded to a demonstration of some sort. You shouldn't use any shorthand when demonstrating code to an audience who will/might not know the language.

Comment: Ok, It's just that almost every language I know has a ternary: Ruby, C, C++, C#, PHP, Java... the list goes on.  I'm not a functional guy (though I toy around), but it seems like we cover a whole lot of programmers by saying *"...people who have a FP background [or] are in the habit of shortening their code in C-like languages."*  Anyways, not a biggie.